# How to convert nested Java 8 future to Java 1.6?

Tags: java

I have the following method in a class:

```
private Future<Integer> myFuture = null;
myFuture = executorVariable
            .submit(() -> runFuture());
```

I changed it to:

```
myFuture= executorVariable.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runFuture()
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error with types. `myFuture` is an `<Integer>` and not a `<?>`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a

```
new Callable<Integer>() {
  @Override public Integer call() {
    return runFuture();
  }
}
```

instead of `Runnable`.  `Runnable` doesn't return a result, but `Callable` does.

Comment: I have an executorVariable that I submit to in my Java 1.8 implementation as referenced in my OP, what happened to it?

Comment: That's probably not what you want to do, but if it's an `ExecutorService` you can `submit` `Callable`s to it.

Comment: It is an executorService. Could you update your answer to refect this?

Comment: I mean, just replacing the runnable with the callable and leaving the rest of your code should work, so I'm not sure what else you want to see in the answer?

Answer (score 2):

The method `submit(Runnable)` of `ExecutorService` does not yield a `Future<Integer>` but a `Future<?>` as `Runnable.run()`'s return type is void.

You can change your results variable declaration to `Future<?>` :

```
Future<?> myFuture;
```

or submit a `Callable<Integer>` to your executor:

```
myFuture= executorVariable.submit(new Callable<>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call() {
        return runFuture(); // or return some other Integer            
    }
});
```

or provide a default return value by using `ExectuorService.submit(Runnable, T)`:

```
myFuture= executorVariable.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runFuture();
    }
} ,(Integer) null /* or some other integer*/);
```

I think the second solution would suits you the best as your lambda-expression in the orignal statement does not produce a `Runnable` but a `Callable<Integer>`.